# How to sample points from a data set using a grid?

Tags: python, interpolation, sampling

So I have some data with around a million `(r, phi)` coordinates, along with their intensities. I want to sample this data in a grid pattern so I can reduce memory used, and plot faster. However I want to sample the data in X,Y as I will be converting the coordinates to `(X,Y)` coordinates to plot them.

I was thinking I could use a meshgrid to come up with a template I'd like to sample, but I'm stuck on the next step.

I can't seem to find anything useful searching on google or here, but apologies if this is too simple a question!

I'm using numpy and my data is stored as three seperate arrays right now. I was planning to use `np.meshgrid` and later `scipy.interpolate.griddata` for interpolation.

`r`, `phi` and `intensity` are all `np.array`s with shape `(million,)`

e.g.

```
r = array([1560.8, 1560.8003119, 1560.8006238, ..., 3556.831746,
           3558.815873 , 3560.8      ])
```

I started with this;

```
r = data[:, 0]  # radius
phi = data[:, 1]  # altitude angle
h2o = data[:, 2]  # intensity

x = r * np.sin(phi)  # It's a left handed coordinate system
z = r * np.cos(phi)
```

And for the sampling grid I have got this;

```
Xscale = np.linspace(min(x), max(x), 1000)
Zscale = np.linspace(min(z), max(z), 1000)

[X, Z] = np.meshgrid(Xscale, Zscale)
```

Comment: You have a Python tag, are you using python with some framework like Pandas or anything similar? Can you please add more details in your question and a sample of your data structure and/or code you have used so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would have been nice if you have provided some data to work on.
It doesn't matter, we will create some.

Lets create x,y values from r,theta arbitrary values :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

theta=np.linspace(0.,50.,1000)
r=np.linspace(5.,10,1000)

x=r*np.sin(theta)
y=r*np.cos(theta)

plt.plot(x,y,linestyle='',marker='.')
```

The plot gives :

[image]

Now add arbitrary intensity values :

```
intensity=np.sqrt(x**2+y**2)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(x, y, intensity)
```

The scatter plot gives :

[image]

If I understand well we should not be far from your starting point. We have now 3 arrays with 1000 values. We are going to reduce it to a 20x20 mesgrid.
We have to first create the x and y bins, then call the binned_statistic_2d method from scipy and that's it.

```
import scipy.stats as stats

binx=np.linspace(-10.,10.,20)
biny=np.linspace(-10.,10.,20)

ret = stats.binned_statistic_2d(x, y, intensity, 'mean', bins=[binx,biny])

Z=ret.statistic
Z = np.ma.masked_invalid(Z) # allow to mask Nan values got in bins where there is no value
X, Y = np.meshgrid(binx,biny)

plt.pcolor(X,Y,Z)
plt.show()
```

The pcolor plot gives :

[image]

As requested in your comment, we can now go back to the original x,y,z arrays structure.

First, we have to calculate the center coordinates of the bins

```
binx_centers=(binx[1:] + binx[:-1])/2
biny_centers=(biny[1:] + biny[:-1])/2
Xcenters, Ycenters = np.meshgrid(binx_centers,biny_centers)
```

Then we can get the not masked values (see explanation above)

```
xnew=np.ma.masked_array(Xcenters, Z.mask).compressed()
ynew=np.ma.masked_array(Ycenters, Z.mask).compressed()
znew=Z.compressed()
```

We can check the new size :

```
print(znew.shape)
```

Gives only 235 values (instead of 1000.):

```
(235L,)
```

And the new scatter plot with the compressed values :

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(xnew, ynew, znew)
```

We obtain :

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is really useful! Is there a way to do this that results in a more versatile end product? As far as I can tell this can only really be plotted using pcolor. Is there a way to transform this into 'normal' coordinates i.e. a 3 column array ([ X Y Z])? Sorry if this is obvious!

Comment: I have edited the answer to include the computation of X Y Z arrays starting from the meshgrid.